# How to access child element property in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating multi-level-Accordion-menu component on React Redux.

```
class MultiLevelAccordianMenu extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.toggleList = this.toggleList.bind(this);

    }
    toggleList(event){
        console.log(event)
    }
    render(){
        return( <ul className="cd-accordion-menu animated">
            <li className="has-children" onClick={this.toggleList}>
                <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1" defaultChecked />
                <label htmlFor="group-1">Group 1</label>

                <ul>
                    <li className="has-children">
                        <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1" />
                        <label htmlFor="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>        );
    }
  }
export default MultiLevelAccordianMenu;
```

while clicking on parent "li" element, i want to toggle the child "ul" element. 
I have written a toggle function. In this how can i access and set the child property to make hide and show?

[image]

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: No I'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and change it on click. Just make *className* of your child element dynamic:

```
class MultiLevelAccordianMenu extends PureComponent {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isActive : false
        };
        this.toggleList = this.toggleList.bind(this);
     }
     toggleList(event){
        this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive});
     }
    render(){
        ....
        <li className="has-children" onClick={this.toggleList}>
        .....               
        <ul className={this.state.isActive ? "active" : ""}>
          ....

}
```

and add to your css something like:

```
ul{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.active{ 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

If you want to add animation you can use css rule [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp):

```
ul{
   max-height: 0;
   transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
   overflow: hidden;
}
ul.active {
   max-height: 500px;
   transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman Romanovsky. I'll try this, But this will work fine for only one children. If we want to achive it for parent-child-grandchildren how can we do this? for ex: render(){ .... <li onClick={this.toggleList()}> <ul className={this.state.active ? "active" : " "}>  <li> <ul> .... </ul> </li> </ul> </li>  <li> <ul> .... </ul></li>}